# Which are the Community Ads for DevOps.SE on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Many mature/graduated StackExchange (SE) meta sites allow posting [Community Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/community-ads-faq) for promoting other SE sites (or site proposals) dedicated to more or less related subject matters.

What is the (complete) list of all such ads posted for DevOps.SE that members of those sites can upvote to help promote this site?

Answer (score 6):

The following is the list of the known community ads for our site (please try to maintain the alphabetical order and the consistency of the list entry format):

- [Drupal](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3697/73480)
- [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9243/community-promotion-ads-2018/9255#9255)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/community-promotion-ads-2018/8697#8697)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/community-promotion-ads-2018/4783#4783)

Note: Stack Overflow doesn't accept community ads anymore, see [Do we need community promotion ads?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284493/do-we-need-community-promotion-ads)

Comment: The ad image needs to be hosted on the Stack Exchange Imgur instance to work as a community ad; I think you'll need to upload them to `i.stack.imgur.com` for them to meet the guidelines. That will break the dynamic counter, unfortunately — perhaps a custom designed ad would be good if anyone has some design skills?

Comment: Same guidelines were there last year, probably to prevent trouble with hosting in unreliable places. There is a check in place, but only runs at initial ad creation, not at subsequent edits. The dynamic picture worked just fine, I saw the actual ad myself a few of times on one of the sites.

Comment: That's not to say I'm not in favor of a more decent ad - I'm all for it. I just completely lack the artistic gene :)